# string escaping with non-nullable named parameters

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to use the google cloud endpoints Java from android as such:

client:

```
Core.Builder coreBuilder = new Core.Builder(
                AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), null);
coreBuilder.setApplicationName("myapp");

if (MainActivity.ENDPOINTS_URL != null) {
    coreBuilder.setRootUrl(MainActivity.ENDPOINTS_URL);
    coreBuilder.setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
        public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> request)
                        throws IOException {
            request.setDisableGZipContent(true);
        }
    });
}

Core core = coreBuilder.build();
myList = core.asdf("x=&+x", myObject);
```

server:

```
 @ApiMethod(name = "asdf")
    public List<String> asdf(@Named("param1") String param1, MyObject myObject) {
    if (param1.equals("x=&+x")) {
    //should go here, but never does
    }
    ...
```

While it mostly works, somehow the param1 string does not get correctly transmitted, meaning that "x=&+x" arrives at the server as "x=&%2Bx". Is this a known bug? Or do arguments have to be manually encoded somehow? Or is this somehow particular to my environment?

Appengine SDK V1.8.8 for java, google api 1.17.0-rc, using the dev environment.

Cheers,
Andres

Comment: As I understand it, strings are URL encoded so that they can be passed via URL, but they are usually decoded in the endpoint class. Are you testing this on the local dev server or has the app been deployed? If locally, try deploying and see if the problem persists.

Comment: It works on production appengine. This is using the local development environment (`mvn appengine:devserver` or IntelliJ appengine plugin) with the endpoint in android set  to allow debugging (I updated the post for details).

Comment: Yeah, I've had similar experiences. It's been a bug since the 1.7.x versions, though things have improved in the 1.8.x series in that you can use the string you receive to query the datastore. For me it just means that certain aspects of my app I always test on a deployed version.